# Link Tables with non exact information only matching the last three last letters

Tags: ms-access

I have searched Stack Overflow and cannot find a way to match two fields based on the only the last three letters of the second field.  I am not great at VBS but can get by.  Here are the details:

Microsoft Access 2010. This is and Aircraft registration database.  The first 4 letters in a field have a consistent length in the first database. Eg.

FABC
GPJR
IDTC
GPPC

The intended join field in the second database can look like this:

CFABC
C-FABC
ABC
C-GPJR
GPJR
PJR
CGPJR

I just need to take the last three letters in the first table and the last three letters in the second table and match them.  It will likely be a make table query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Jeff

Comment: What do you mean by join? That has a very specific meaning in Access (or SQL, more accurately) that I'm not sure fits your use case. What is your end goal here?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Anthony. The join is to look up matching data just like a standard join with some adjustments for what to look for specific data to join.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is as such:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table1, Table 2    
WHERE (((Right([Table1].[ID],3))=Right([Table2].[ID],3)));
```

Comment: Thanks Random.  I am not familiar with Select ID but assuming the fields I will be working with.  Otherwise I am familiar with the cool WHERE statement. Just couldn't think of the syntax.